# Summarising rows and columns from known groupings

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a symmetrical matrix of flows (in `tibble` form) similar to the below example:

```r
library(tibble)
set.seed(2019)

df1 <- as_tibble(matrix(sample(1:10,100,replace = T), nrow = 10, ncol = 10, byrow = TRUE,
               dimnames = list(as.character(1:10),
                               as.character(1:10))))

df1
#     `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`   `6`   `7`   `8`   `9`  `10`
#   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1     8     8     4     7     1     1     9     1     2     7
# 2     8     7     3     2     7     7     1     8     4     5
# 3     5     6    10     2     2     1     6    10     7     5
# 4     7     1     9     2     1     1     4     5     1     8
# 5     7     3     9     7     9     5    10    10     3     2
# 6     4     1     1     4     6     4    10    10     1     1
# 7     2     3     8     4     8    10     4     1     9     6
# 8     4     2     4     2     7    10     2     6     4     8
# 9     1    10    10     3     6     2     6     7     8     4
#10     6     8     9     3     6     9     5    10     4    10
```

I also have a lookup table that shows the broad groups that each flow subgroup fits into:

```r
lookup <- tibble(sector = as.character(1:10),
                     aggregate_sector = c(rep('A',3), rep('B', 3), rep('C', 4)))
lookup
#   sector aggregate_sector
#1       1                A
#2       2                A
#3       3                A
#4       4                B
#5       5                B
#6       6                B
#7       7                C
#8       8                C
#9       9                C
#10     10                C
```

I want to summarise my original `df1` such that it represents the flows between each `aggregate_sector` (as per the lookup table) rather than each `sector`. Expected output:

```r
#   A  B  C
#A 59 30 65
#B 42 39 65
#C 67 70 94
```

My initial attempt has been to convert into a matrix and then use a nested `for` loop to calculate the sum of flows for each `aggregate_sector` combination in turn:

```r
mdat <- as.matrix(df1)

# replace row and column names with group names - assumes lookup is in same order as row and col names...
row.names(mdat) <- lookup$aggregate_sector
colnames(mdat) <- lookup$aggregate_sector

# pre-allocate an empty matrix
new_mat <- matrix(nrow = 3, ncol = 3, dimnames = list(LETTERS[1:3], LETTERS[1:3]))

# fill in matrix section by section
for(i in row.names(new_mat)){
  for(j in colnames(new_mat)){
    new_mat[i,j] <- sum(mdat[which(row.names(mdat) ==i), which(colnames(mdat) ==j)])
  }
}


new_mat

#   A  B  C
#A 59 30 65
#B 42 39 65
#C 67 70 94
```

While this is a satisfactory solution, I wonder if there's a solution using `dplyr` or similar that uses nicer logic and saves me from having to convert my actual data (which is a `tibble`) into matrix form.

Comment: First `tidyr::gather` on `df1` then double `left_join` `df1` and `df2` (once on sector source and once on sector target) then `group_by` `sector_from` and `sector_to` and `sum`... Easy peasy :)

Comment: @antoine-sac yeah you're totally right.. I knew there was a simpler logic to it, just had my data in the wrong kinda format. Feel free to post some kind of answer based on that and I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key steps is to gather - after that is it all straightforward dplyr stuff:

```r
flow_by_sector <- 
  df1 %>%
  mutate(sector_from = rownames(.)) %>%
  tidyr::gather(sector_to, flow, -sector_from)


flow_by_sector_with_agg <- 
  flow_by_sector %>%
  left_join(lookup, by = c("sector_from" = "sector")) %>%
  rename(agg_from = aggregate_sector) %>%
  left_join(lookup, by = c("sector_to" = "sector")) %>%
  rename(agg_to = aggregate_sector)

flow_by_agg <- 
  flow_by_sector_with_agg %>%
  group_by(agg_from, agg_to) %>%
  summarise(flow = sum(flow))

tidyr::spread(flow_by_agg, agg_to, flow)
```

Comment: Perfect! I think the very final step to get my exact 'expected output' would be to use `spread(flow_by_agg, agg_to, flow) %>%
  column_to_rownames( var = "agg_from")`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base answer that uses `stack` and `xtabs`. It's not super robust - it assumes that the lookup table has the same columns and order as what would be expressed in the `data.frame`.

```
colnames(df1) <- lookup$aggregate_sector

xtabs(values ~ sector + ind
      , dat = data.frame(sector = rep(lookup$aggregate_sector
                                    , length(df1)), stack(df1))
      )
```

Here's another way to do the data.frame:

```
xtabs(values ~ Var1 + Var2,
      dat = data.frame(expand.grid(lookup$aggregate_sector, lookup$aggregate_sector)
                       , values = unlist(df1))
)
    Var2
Var1  A  B  C
   A 59 30 65
   B 42 39 65
   C 67 70 94
```

Comment: Thanks, I've never used xtabs but it looks very useful for things like this. As you say, it feels a bit precarious due to its reliance on order but it does work well.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured out a matrix algebra alternative to my problem which is much faster despite having to convert my `data.frame` into a `matrix`. I won't accept this solution as I did ask specifically for a `dplyr` answer, but thought it interesting enough to post here anyway.

I first had to form an adjustment matrix, S, from my lookup table where the the locations of ones in row i of S indicate which sectors of the original matrix will be grouped together as sector i in the aggregated matrix:

```r
S <- lookup %>% mutate(sector = as.numeric(sector), value = 1)  %>%
  spread(sector, value) %>%
  column_to_rownames('aggregate_sector') %>%
  as.matrix()

S[is.na(S)] <- 0

S

#  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#A 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0  0
#B 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0  0
#C 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1  1
```

Then, I convert my original `data.frame`, df1, into `matrix` x and simply calculate S.x.S' :

```r
x <- as.matrix(df1)

S %*% x %*% t(S)

#   A  B  C
#A 59 30 65
#B 42 39 65
#C 67 70 94
```